# Query String and XSS

Tags: php, xss, query-string

A recent PCI scan of our ecommerce site shows that every page on our site is subject to XSS issues. The specific issue is the query-string; e.g:

> www.website.com?c=[script]alert('TK000000B1')[/script]

Every PHP page also has a `header.php` that is included for all pages on our website.

Is there a single line of code that I could add to my `header.php` header template file to clean the query string?

IE something like adding these 2 lines of PHP code (below is an example, not a solution):

```
INPUT_POST = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); 
INPUT_SERVER = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'QUERY_STRING', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

In other words, can I take the query string, clean it, and set it back (equal) to the query string value for the rest of the program to properly process it?

Comment: No. Fix whatever is just blindly outputting `$_GET['c']` into the page. Don't patch over it, fix it.

Comment: You can use `htmlspecialchars` https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp in all `$_POST` and `$_GET` values for prevent xss. [1]:

Comment: No. And the worse news is that it looks like some kind of markdown code is responsible for your XSS issue; native PHP functions like `htmlspecialchars` won't help you; the only character it touches in `[script]alert('TK000000B1')[/script]` is the singel quote. And there are ways to inject javascript without using a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer you are looking for, but you should find the error and fix it.

```
<?php
//include this on all php files first.
// this will run all the values and run the htmlentities against all of them.
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){

  $_GET[$key] = htmlentities($value);
}

// also you must do the same for the post values.

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){

  $_POST[$key] = htmlentities($value);
}
?>
```

Please note that it will parse all user inputs with htmlentities, is not the best solution and may affect some user input..

Also is not going to make your code safe to XSS, they are a lot of things that users can send to your post variables like SQL injection (or 1=1; //).